# Is it possible to add table of contents like to python script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I love Jupyter notebook. One of reasons is it has table of contents which is very convenient to search and organize big codes. However Jupyter notebook or Jupyter lab is very slow for a big notebook file. So I am thinking to convert notebook back to py file.

I am wondering if there is any IDE where I can add markdown to the script and then can add table of contents to py file like notebook does?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you can checkout [nbdev](https://github.blog/2020-11-20-nbdev-a-literate-programming-environment-that-democratizes-software-engineering-best-practices/).

Comment: Anyone has some ideas to share? Thanks